# Selecting TOC content as per custom tag in Aspose word

Tags: java, tableofcontents, aspose.words

I am using Aspose word 18.9. We know that the default way to insert Table of content is :

```
builder.InsertTableOfContents("\\o \"1-3\" \\h \\z \\u");
```

Here Only `H1-H3` tags will be considered for TOC. But Header tags create extra spaces in the content which I don't want.

So I want to use user-defined tag for TOC. Currently I have created user-defined tag `toc`.

For example:

```
<toc>Heading 1</toc>
<toc>Heading 2</toc>
```

I want this tag to be used to build the TOC.

Is there any way to do so?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

@Newinjava I think, in your case, you can use [TC (Table of Contents Entry)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-tc-table-of-contents-entry-field-01e5dd8a-4730-4bc2-8594-23d7329e25c3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) field instead of your custom tags. Then you can use '\f EntryIdentifier' To build [TOC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-toc-table-of-contents-field-1f538bc4-60e6-4854-9f64-67754d78d05c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).
For example you insert TOC with the following switches:

```
{ TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u \f mycoolid }
```

Then you inset TC fields like this to build TOC

```
{ TC  "first level" \f mycoolid \l 1 }
{ TC  "second level" \f mycoolid \l 2 }
{ TC  "third level" \f mycoolid \l 3 }
```

You can insert such fields programmatically using [DocumentBuilder.InsertField](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.documentbuilder/insertfield/methods/1) method or using MS Word.